# A variable has no status key, but var.status gives string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Its a mongoose/express app, I have a route like this:

```
// ..
Posts.find({})
.then(function(posts) {
  var data = _.chain(posts).filter(function(post) {
    if(post.comment) {
      return post.updatedAt <= post.comment.lastCreatedAt;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }).each(function(post) {
    if(post.comment) {
      post.status = 'OK';
    } else {
      post.status = 'NOT OK';
    } 
    console.log("post")
    console.log(post)
    console.log("post.status")
    console.log(post.status)
  }).value();   
})
// ..
```

But the log is

```
"post"
{
  _id: ***,
  title: 'test',
  content: 'test',
  user: ***
}
"post.status"
OK
```

why there's no status in first `console.log(post)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post is a [Document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js) object which means it has a custom [toJSON](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON) method that only yields the properties of your schema and the _id.

You can get an object representation of the document via the `toObject` method.